# Concat strings inside Array in SimpleAdapter

Tags: java, android, arrays, concatenation, listadapter

I have following statement in Java (Android development):

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                MainActivity.this, list,
                R.layout.list_item, new String[] {JSON_ADDRESS,JSON_STATE}, new int[] { R.id.address,R.id.state});
```

Now I want to have on the r.id.address element JSON_ADDRESS + JSONNUMBER (another constant).

```
... new String[] {JSON_ADDRESS + " " + JSON_NUMBER, JSON_STATE}...
```

The above doesn't work. It displays nothing at all on the first element...
Anyone who can help concatenate the two variables?

Thanks in regard!

Comment: The problem is not with the code which you posted here.

Comment: It works with only 1 variable, so I guess the rest of the code is just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String result = String.format("%s %s %s",JSON_ADDRESS,JSON_NUMBER,JSON_STATE);
Example - address is "a"
          number is "b" 
          state is "c"
result will be - "a b c"
```

$s - Strings
$d - Numbers.

Comment: string.Format doesn't work...

Comment: what are the types of the variables?

Comment: both string variables

Comment: Now it works, thanks! Would have found it nice if there was a solution without using a second variable, but this works fine thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to create your own custom list adapter. See [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterown) for an example on how to do that.